# When using Immutable.JS, should redux selectors always return Immutable.JS objects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reselect

The Redux Team suggests [selectors always return Immutable.JS objects](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#your-selectors-should-return-immutablejs-objects) .However, I find it's difficult for selectors to return Immutable.JS objects when selectors' returning objects are constructed by  multiple slices of the state.

Take the official [shopping-cart](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart) demo as an example. The selector `getCartProducts` uses both the cart slice and the product slice of the state to construct the returning object:

```
export const getCartProducts = state =>
  getAddedIds(state).map(id => ({
    ...getProduct(state, id),
    quantity: getQuantity(state, id)
  }))
```

In this case, if using Immutable.JS, how to reconstruct this selector to let it return a Immutable.JS object?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to not mutate the state, but you can do this without Immutable.JS

> You do not need to use Immutable.JS with Redux. Plain JavaScript, if written correctly, is perfectly capable of providing immutability without having to use an immutable-focused library. [redux faq](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html#what-approaches-are-there-for-handling-data-immutably-do-i-have-to-use-immutablejs)

Comment: I know how to write immutable state without immutable-focused library. But I wonder how to deal with the case mentioned in my question when using Immutable.JS. That's my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Immutable JS object and use method .map on it, it will return new ImmutableJs object.

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/map

If you have vanilla JS object and want to convert it to Immutable.js there is helper function fromJS()
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS

```
let some = {foo: 'bar'};
let immutableObject = Immutable.fromJS(some);
```

so couple options.

1. make sure you are running map function on Immutable.js structure
2. run as it is now and after done transfer from vanilla to Immutable.js using Immutable.fromJS()

Comment: Thanks. But maybe you did't get my point. My point is whether selectors should always return Immutable.JS objects when using Immutable.JS or not ? In the case I mentioned, It seems selectors returning  a plain JS Object is more reasonable.

Comment: If you have immutable.js structure it will return immutable.js objects or node values. If node value is js object, it will return js object.

Answer (score 0):

If your whole redux state is an immutable.js object, all those functions are going to return an immutable.js object. Per example, `getAddedIds(state)` function will return an Immutable.List and the `map` function will return a new Immutable.List. As you shouldn't never mix plain JS objects with Immutable.js objects, the objects inside those Lists will be an Immutable.js as well.

I tried to create a simple example to show you how these selectors would look like

```js
const ids = [
  'a2ds2',
  'a3322asdda',
  '1d1w1s11x1'
];

const products = [{
  id: 'a2ds2',
  name: 'milk'
},
{
  id:'a3322asdda',
  name: 'bread'
},
{
  id:'b1d1w1s11x1',
  name: 'orange'
}
];

const cartItems = [
{
  productId: 'a3322asdda',
  qnt: 20
},
{
  productId: 'a2ds2',
  qnt: 3
}
]

const newState = Immutable.fromJS({
  ids, 
  products,
  cartItems
})

// returns an List of ids
const getAddedIds = (state) => state.get('ids').filter(id => id[0] === 'a')

// returns an product Map
const getProduct = (state, id) => state.get('products').find(product => product.get('id') === id)

// returns the qnt of a product
const getQntByProduct = (state, id) => state.get('cartItems').find(item => item.get('productId') === id).get('qnt')

// create the new List
const result = getAddedIds(newState)
  .map(id => getProduct(newState, id).set(
          'qnt', 
          getQntByProduct(newState, id)
        )
  )

console.log('result', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```